# Save vueJs in localStorage

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-storage

I would like to keep my game going after page refresh (either local Storage or sesion Storage).
I've managed to keep wins in localStorage, but cant figure it out, how to keep table with "X" and "O" is same spot after refresh.
Does anyone have any ideas?

```
import { ref, computed, watch, onMounted } from "vue";

const player = ref("X");
const table = ref([
  ["", "", ""],
  ["", "", ""],
  ["", "", ""],
]);

const CalculateWinner = (squares) => {
  const lines = [
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 8],
    [0, 3, 6],
    [1, 4, 7],
    [2, 5, 8],
    [0, 4, 8],
    [2, 4, 6],
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    const [a, b, c] = lines[i];
    if (squares[a] && squares[a] === squares[b] && squares[a] === squares[c]) {
      return squares[a];
    }
  }
  return null;
};

const winner = computed(() => CalculateWinner(table.value.flat()));

const Move = (x, y) => {
  if (winner.value) return;

  if (table.value[x][y] !== "") return;

  table.value[x][y] = player.value;

  player.value = player.value === "X" ? "O" : "X";
};

const Reset = () => {
  table.value = [
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
    ["", "", ""],
  ];
  player.value = "X";
};

const history = ref([]);
watch(winner, (current, previous) => {
  if (current && !previous) {
    history.value.push(current);
    localStorage.setItem("history", JSON.stringify(history.value));
  }
});

onMounted(() => {
  history.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("history")) ?? [];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the exact same way you did for `history`:

- At each move (so inside method `Move`), you can save the full table in local storage using `localStorage.setItem("table", JSON.stringify(table.value));`
- Then in the `onMounted` method, retrieve the saved value from local storage using `table.value = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("table"));`
  Do not forget to call `Reset` if table.value is null, to prevent failure at first launch.

If you also want to store who is currently playing, you can save it under a third variable (e.g. "player") inside local storage or you could also create an object to represent the whole status of the current game and put inside the table and player.

Have fun with Vue!